# How to set/get/save data in session storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage, sessionstorage

here is example of my data that I get after ajax call response is successful `obj.DATA` looks like this:

```
{
  "A43D": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Mike",
    "EMAIL": "mjohns@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Johns"
  },
  "4E83": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Steve",
    "EMAIL": "scook@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Cook"
  }
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'AjaxFunctions.cfc?method=getCustomers',
   data: formData,
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
   console.log(obj.DATA);
   sessionStorage.setItem("customersData", JSON.stringify(obj.DATA));      
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert('Error: '+errorThrown);
});
```

Then I dump `sessionStorage` in `console.log(sessionStorage)` and I see this:

```
{
  "customersData": "{\"A43D\":{\"FIRSTNAME\":\"Mike\",\"EMAIL\":\"mjohnes@gmail.com\",\"LASTNAME\":\"Johnes\"},\"4E83\":{\"FIRSTNAME\":\"Steve\",\"EMAIL\":\"scook@gmail.com\",\"LASTNAME\":\"Cook\"}}"
}
```

So I was trying next:

```
sessionData = sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty(customersData[recordID]) ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(customersData[recordID])) : null;
```

This is in the function where I just pass record id and then try to access that record in session storage. If I try to `console.log(sessionData)` all I see is `null`. I'm wondering how I can access specific key in customersData object inside of the session storage? Also how I would insert/edit record in sessionStorage customersData object?

Comment: `sessionStorage.getItem("customersData")` will return you the JSON you stored there. You need to run it through `JSON.parse()` to get an object out again.

Comment: @vlaz How I would check for existence of the `recordID` in sessionStorage? Seems little over complicated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each time you try to save/load something for the localStorage/sessionStorage and you know it is a json object, always stringify/parse it depending on the case.

here you have your code fixed to work.

**NOTE:** I tried to create a snippet but it didn't work because we can not access to the sessionStorage of a sandbox.

**NOTE2:** always check what data are you going to parse, if the record doesnt exist on the storage, it will return `null`.

```
var data = {
  "A43D": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Mike",
    "EMAIL": "mjohns@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Johns"
  },
  "4E83": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Steve",
    "EMAIL": "scook@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Cook"
  }
}

//here we save the item in the sessionStorage.
sessionStorage.setItem("customersData", JSON.stringify(data));


//now we retrieve the object again, but in a string form.
var customersDataString = sessionStorage.getItem("customersData");
console.log(customersDataString);

//to get the object we have to parse it.
var customersData = JSON.parse(customersDataString);
console.log(customersData);
```

Comment: How to get recordID ? I see what you did, you pulled all record from customersData but then I need specific record with an id I passed...

Comment: @espresso_coffee that is another logic. after retrieving the json object you can just do a check after like this


    `if(customersData[recordID]){ //do something ....     }`

Comment: So the trick is JSON.parse and then pull record from JSON object.

Comment: exactly, you wont be able to handle the items directly from the session storage, because it only saves strings. so you need to fetch the records and parse them again to an object, after that you will be able to loop/search/do whatever you want.

Comment: That works, I just tried. I thought my original solution would work but this is the way to go. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @espresso_coffee glad I was able to help you. remember to mark this as the answer.

Comment: One more thing we missed, how to insert or update record in customersData session storage?

Comment: @espresso_coffee that is easy, after you do magic with your `customersData` go and save it again as before with `sessionStorage.setItem("customersData", JSON.stringify(customersData));`

Comment: Would that insert duplicate key/id if I do not check before the insert?

Comment: @espresso_coffee nope, it wouldnt. think this like an object
if you retrieve `var x = obj[prop]` and  then modify `x` to have a different value and then you do `obj[prop]=x` it will override the value of `obj[prop]`.
the same applies to the storage, if you set a value, it doesnt matter if it was already set, it will override it.

Comment: I have tried this for updating record in session storage but value never updates: `var sessionData = sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty("accountData") ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("accountData")) : null,                    frmSerializeArray = $('#'+frmID).serializeArray();if(sessionData !== null && sessionData[obj.RECID]){
                    sessionData[obj.RECID] = JSON.stringify(getJSON(frmSerializeArray));
                }else{
                    sessionData[obj.RECID] = JSON.stringify(getJSON(frmSerializeArray));
                }` getJSON() will return json object.

Comment: @espresso_coffee
actually try to change your `IF` to this:

if (sessionData !== null && sessionData[obj.RECID]) {
  sessionData.setItem(obj.RECID, JSON.stringify(getJSON(frmSerializeArray)));
} else {
  sessionData.setItem(obj.RECID, JSON.stringify(getJSON(frmSerializeArray)));
}

Comment: I have tried and error showed `TypeError: sessionData.setItem is not a function`. I'm not sure if your proposed solution will work since I have to insert data in customersData object inside of the session storage and update the key.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach this,
by creating some `customersStorage` Object with **methods** like `get`, `set` and `add`

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ou2ax645/)**

```
var customersStorage = {
    // Get all or single customer by passing an ID
    get: function( id ) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.customersData || "{}");
        return id ? parsed[id] : parsed;
    },
    // Set all
    set: function( obj ) {
        return sessionStorage.customersData = JSON.stringify(obj || {});
    },
    // Add single customer and store
    add: function( id, obj ) {
        var all = this.get();
        // Make sure customer does not exists already;
        if(all.hasOwnProperty(id)) return console.warn(id+ " exists!");
        all[id] = obj;
        return this.set(all);
    }
};

// Let's play!

// Store All
customersStorage.set({
  "A43D": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Mike",
    "EMAIL": "mjohns@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Johns"
  },
  "4E83": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "Steve",
    "EMAIL": "scook@gmail.com",
    "LASTNAME": "Cook"
  }
});

// Get single
console.log( customersStorage.get("4E83") );

// Add new 
customersStorage.add("AAA0", {
  "FIRSTNAME": "Espresso",
  "LASTNAME": "Coffee",
  "EMAIL": "espresso@coffee.com"
});

// Get all
console.log( customersStorage.get() );
```

Furthermore, to make your session handling object more *"client"* agnostic I'd expand it to handle even more data by *namespace*:

```
var ObjectStorage = function(nsp, useSession) {
  var stg = (useSession ? sessionStorage : localStorage);
  return {
    // Get all or single customer by passing an ID
    get: function(id) {
      var parsed = JSON.parse(stg[nsp] || "{}");
      return id ? parsed[id] : parsed;
    },
    // Set all
    set: function(obj) {
      return stg[nsp] = JSON.stringify(obj || {});
    },
    // Add one to all
    add: function(prop, val) {
      var all = this.get();
      // Make sure property does not exists already;
      if (all.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return console.warn(prop + " exists!");
      all[prop] = val;
      return this.set(all);
    }
  }
};

// Let's play!

// Create instance. Use true to use sessionStorage (instead of localStorage)
var Customers = new ObjectStorage("customersData", true);
// now you can use .add(), .get(), .set() on your Customers Object
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do but I do not see values updated for existing records: `var sessionData = sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty("customersData") ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("customersData")) : null,
                    frmSerializeArray = $('#'+frmID).serializeArray();
                
                if(sessionData !== null && sessionData[obj.RECID]){
                    sessionData[obj.RECID] = JSON.stringify(getJSON(frmSerializeArray));
                }else{
                    sessionData[obj.RECID] = getJSON(frmSerializeArray);
                }`

Comment: To update existing ones, simply remove the *if* line from the .add() method