# How to display Alert-info box only once a session without cookies

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created an alert-info box in bootstrap 3 and managed to create that it fades away after 10 seconds. But I want this box only to shown once a browser session (and not showing on each page reload how it is now).

Prefer not using a cookie, but instead sessionStorage

Here is my html code:

```
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-success credits center" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h2>text </h2> text 2
                    <div class="row margin-t-10">
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 col1 center-block">
                       <a href="#"><button class="button btn-success btn-block" > text 3<span style="font-size:17px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>
                    </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
$(".alert-credit, .alert-info").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
});
}, 9000);
```

How can I get it that the alert-info box only shows once a session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set/get/save data in session storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180134/how-to-set-get-save-data-in-session-storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save an entry in `sessionStorage` when the alert is shown, and check if it exists before showing the alert:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('alertShown') === null){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".alert-credit, .alert-info").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
          sessionStorage.setItem('alertShown', 'true');
          $(this).remove(); 
      });   
  }, 9000);
}else{
    $(".alert-credit, .alert-info").remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer!

I used your code, but now the alert-info box does not fade away anymore after 10 seconds. And it also still shows up after a page reload.

Comment: is the alert box visible by default?

Comment: Yes, the box is visible by default

Comment: try that then, but that's inefficient, you should rather have the alert hidden by default with css and then only show it and fade it the first time the user loads the page - using the if block from above (without else)